# the field of fractions of a domain $R$ does not have a projective cover if $R$ is not a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, modules

Let $R$ be an integer domain (so it commutes) that is not a field. Let $K$ be its field of fractions (also called localization). Prove that $K$ does not have a projective cover ( naturally viewed as an $R$ module, a left $R$ module to be precise). Unfortunately I am not very sure how to proceed.

Comment: Can you do it for the integers? One thing you can look for is: does Q have a minimal set of generators over Z? How does that translate to projective that cover it? (Recall that projective = free over Z)

Comment: yeah, I can${}{}{}$